# How can I make the "High Five!" taunt togglable?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Recently I got the "High Five!" taunt and according to the wiki description you have to hold down the "action" key and then wait for another player to come over to you and press their taunt key.

"When the player holds down the action button, their character will enter one of two class-specific poses with the right hand held up high."

The issue I have is that you must hold down the "action" key and for wait someone. I'd like to have it so that when I press the "action" key the game we'll wait until someone initiates the high five.

Long story short: I'd like it so that I don't have to hold down the button and wait. I want the taunt to be togglable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following will replace your default action item H key with a toggle version.  Note that this technique is a fairly standard method of making a toggle out of any `+-` "hold down the button" type of command.

```
bind H toggle_action_item
alias enable_action_item "alias toggle_action_item disable_action_item; +use_action_slot_item"
alias disable_action_item "alias toggle_action_item enable_action_item; -use_action_slot_item" 
alias toggle_action_item enable_action_item
```

If this works and you want to keep it, put it in your `autoexec.cfg`.

Answer (score 0):

Just use
bind H "-use_action_slot_item; +use_action_slot_item"